# How to select Ubuntu on startup

Tags: 12.04, boot, windows-8

I have Ubuntu installed and everything. Only problem is that I can't select it from startup. I have disabled secure boot, and have legacy enabled. I have windows 8 installed already on my hp envy dv7.

Comment: Please indicate your [BootInfo URL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info) , and indicate exactly what you observe at startup.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5871883/ and it just loads straight into windows 8 and doesn't give me an option to select ubuntu.

Comment: run Boot-Repair's Recommended Repair, and indicate the new URL that will appear.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/5873053/

Answer (score 0):

You are affected by this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1090829

Solution1:

1. Via Gparted create another EFI partition (FAT32, 200MB, located in the first 100GB of the disk), move the 'boot' flag on it
2. Install grub-efi in this new ESP (eg https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Converting_Ubuntu_into_EFI_mode ).

Alternative solution:

1. Backup the files in the ESP
2. Format the ESP
3. Recreate the ESP (FAT32, same size) via Gparted, place the 'boot' flag on it
4. Restore the backups into this new ESP
5. Install grub-efi in this new ESP.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).